# Implementing bi-level optimisation time series problem in python

Tags: python, time-series, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I'm working on a project where I have to implement a bi-level optimisation model of a micro grid network in python. The goal is to run the program with some sample data and highlight the benefits of such a system on efficient use of renewable energy produced locally, compared to no optimisation.

The equations are set up as a bi-level optimisation problem, where the "Control Centre" minimises its expense by setting electricity prices (p_sell is the sale price to users, p_dg is the price paid to renewable producers in the network) and power withdrawn from the external grid. On a lower level, a "Prosumer Manager" handles consumers that have both production and consumption (let's say a PV + Battery system for example), which can help with regulation (the DeltaP_dr variable).

To recap: at the upper level, the Control Centre serves as the decision maker who formulates the electricity price strategies to guide the behaviours of the prosumers based on the centralized calculation of the network. At the lower level, the optimization schemes of prosumers can be obtained in response to the electricity price signals of the Control Centre.

These are the equations of the two interconnected problems:

[image: equations of the network problem]

[image: equations of the prosumer problem]

I searched for days to find the right tool to implement these problems but for some reason I can't find tutorials on optimisation of time-series problems.

I know this problem can be implemented by using KKT conditions forming the KKT conditions of the inner problem and add these as constraints to the outer problem. But I have no clue on how to code this in python.

I could add the KKT conditions, even if I'm not sure if they're correct, (shown below) as equations but I don't know how to handle the extra lambda variables.
[image: possible KKT conditions]

I thought Gekko might have been my best bet but it doesn't seem to fit the bi-level needs of this problem (I have asked a question on a different way to implement this problem, but using KKT conditions seems to be the right way to implement the bi-level aspect). [YALMIP](https://yalmip.github.io/example/bilevelprogrammingalternatives/) seems to make the "formulate KKT conditions and add them to another problem" easier but it's on MatLab, so it's a no-go.

What can I do?